# Duda sobre llamar a diferentes tablas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Quisiera saber como ver las Tutorias que tiene un alumno ya que hay varias Tutorias por decir:

***El alumno puede tener mas de 1 Tutoria**

En la tabla alumno tengo esto:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[CLAVE_UNICA]
      ,[NOMBRE]
      ,[APELLIDO_PATERNO]
      ,[APELLIDO_MATERNO]
  FROM [Tutorias].[T].[FCALUMNOS]
```

Despues en la otra tabla de Tutorias tengo esto:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[NUMERO_CITA]
      ,[CLAVE_UNICA]
      ,[VALOR]
      ,[OBSERVACIONES]
  FROM [Tutorias].[T].[TUTORIAS_PRESENCIALES
```

Mi duda es para ver un alumno y que este muestre a que **Tutoria o Tutorias** esta registrado tengo que hacer llave foranea y ademas mandarlo llamar en el programa, si alguien me lo pudiera explicar se lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que entendí si lo que quieres es hacer una consulta de las dos tablas podrías realizarlo con un `INNER JOIN`

ejemplo:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) FCALUMNOS.*,TUTORIAS_PRESENCIALES.*
  FROM [Tutorias].[T].[FCALUMNOS]
INNER JOIN [Tutorias].[T].[TUTORIAS_PRESENCIALES] ON TUTORIAS_PRESENCIALES.CLAVE_UNICA=FCALUMNOS.CLAVE_UNICA
```

espero sea lo que necesitas

Comment: A lo mejor y si es asi, por decir tengo 3 alumnos y 5 Tutorias, lo que quiero saber es ver un alumno y saber a cuales tutorias esta registrado no se si tenga que usar eso que dices tu o una llave foranea?

Comment: El `INNER JOIN` es una instrucción para unir tablas al consultarlas. La llave foránea es un objeto que permite etablecer una relación entre 2 tablas. Uno es código, el otro es diseño.